# How to make a straight parallelogram css for pricetag

Tags: css

I want to make this shape as a background for my price but i dont know how something like this is done.

Does someone know how i can make this in css?
[Pricetag picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV45g.png)

Comment: Have a look into `clip-path` - with no code showing what you've already tried, I can't help you further

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using Transform property and seudo :before or :after

```
.price-tag{
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    max-width: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    transform: rotate(-4deg) skewY(-10deg);
    position: relative;
}

.price-tag:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 105%;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 20px solid dodgerblue;
    border-left: 30px solid #0000;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #0000;
    border-right: 10px solid #0000;
}
```